# Get the ip of virtual machine in microsoft azure via rest API

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I am trying to get detail of a virtual machine via REST API (curl command). I am getting all detail as per [this official documentaion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtualmachines/virtualmachines-get). But I am not able to get IP address. But in portal my vm is assigned to IP address.

Is there any method to get the VM ip adress via linux curl ?

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you mean run curl in Linux to find it's public IP address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any method to get the VM ip adress via linux curl ?

Yes, we can run this command to get VM's Public IP address:
`curl ifconfig.me`

Like this:

```
[root@jasoncli@jasonye ~]# curl ifconfig.me
167.xxx.XX.67
```

---

Update:

we can use this request URI to get IP address information,

```
/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroup}/providers/Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/{publicIPAddressName}?api-version=2016-09-01
```

More information please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/network/virtualnetwork/get-information-about-a-public-ip-address).

Comment: No, I think you  misunderstood my question. I am calling the rest api via curl.
LIKE CURL -x post <URL>
So is there any rest api in azure, which can provide the ip address of my microsoft azure VIRTUAL MACHINE., like I get detail of vm from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtualmachines/virtualmachines-get ?

Comment: @DineshPatra Sorry for my misunderstand, we can get information about the ip address via REST API, please refer to this link `/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroup}/providers/Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/{publicIPAddressName}?api-version={api-version}`https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/network/virtualnetwork/get-information-about-a-public-ip-address

Comment: @DineshPatra Does it work for you? Please let me know if you would like further assistance.

Answer (score 3):

Jason's second response is correct. So Microsoft.Network namespace contains the networking related details like IP Address etc. The documentation that you were referring to was querying the Microsoft.Compute namespace which contains VM details.

Alternatively, you can visit https://resources.azure.com to understand where the information is located.

For example you can browse the following link:
https://resources.azure.com/subscriptions/**<-Subscription-ID->**/providers/Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses

Comment: How would I know which IP is associated with the VM I am interested in?